# MUI DataGrid (Pro) filer settings not shown if filterModel is set using filterModel

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I use a Mui Data Grid, and want to save the filter settings between reloads,
so I put them in a context and the context syncs with the browser session storage.
The filter runs server-side.

The code looks like this:

```js
import {DataGridPro, GridOverlay, GridToolbar, LicenseInfo, useGridApiRef, useGridSlotComponentProps} from '@mui/x-data-grid-pro';

      <DataGridPro
        autoPageSize
        filterMode='server'
        filterModel={appContext.listFilters}
        onFilterModelChange={onFilterChange}
// [...]
/>
```

the filter from `listFilters` looks like this:

```json
[
  {
    "columnField": "foo",
    "id": 50386,
    "operatorValue": "is",
    "value": "bar"
  }
]
```

when the filter is defined it is stored,
after reloading in the browser,
the filter is applied as seen in log output,
then a (few) re-render occurs and
then the filter is reset to an empty value again.

But why?

A simple [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/datagridpro-v5-quick-start-forked-7bu3h) shows the filter is set correctly in a simple case, without re-renders.

Tried it with `autoPageSize` and with fixed `pageSize={20}', as is suspected the` autoPageSize` algorithm needs an extra render to get the right number of rows. But that changed nothing.

I suspect the re-renders are to blame and tried to react DevTools and [why-did-you-render](https://github.com/welldone-software/why-did-you-render) to figure out whats causing the extra renders. but couldn*t figure out what happens.

Any ideas what's wrong here?

PS:
(same goes for sorting...)

Answer (score 0):

Hard to help you if you do not explain what is inside the `onFilterChange` function.

Maybe you do not respect the format of the filter model. The following one is not a valid model

```
[
  {
    "columnField": "foo",
    "id": 50386,
    "operatorValue": "is",
    "value": "bar"
  }
]
```

The [filter model](https://mui.com/api/data-grid/grid-filter-model/#main-content) is an object with two properties: `items` and `linkOperator`

```
{items: [
    {
      "columnField": "foo",
      "id": 50386,
      "operatorValue": "is",
      "value": "bar"
    }
  ]
}
```

Notice that there is a new method `apiRef.current.exportState()` that export most of the state information you could want to restore with initial state. See the [doc page about state management](https://mui.com/components/data-grid/state/#initialize-the-state)